# Crash because DIV instruction ISA: x86-16bit

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

Another problem :)
when I do the division with 16-bit operand, then:

```
DX:AX = AX : r/m16 <-- 16bit(word) operand
```

the program crashes.
This is the program:

```
stack SEGMENT PARA STACk

    db      ?

stack ENDS

data SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC

    db      ?

data ENDS

code SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC

    ASSUME ss: stack, ds: data, cs: code

_start:
    mov     ax, data
    mov     ds, ax

    mov     ax, 10
    mov     dx, 2
    div     dx

    ;output number 10/2 = 5 + 48 = 53(Ascii code '5')
    add     ax, 48
    mov     dx, ax
    mov     ah, 02h
    int     21h

    mov     ah, 04ch
    mov     al, 1
    int     21h

code ENDS
       END _start
```

From what I understand it happens due to an overflow, but where is the overflow here?
also the result of the division is saved in DX and AX? What causes an overflow?

Comment: Look at [this description](https://ulukai.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#insDIV) of `div`: "For DIV `r/m16`, `DX:AX` is divided by the given operand; the quotient is stored in `AX` and the remainder in `DX`." If the divisor is zero or the quotient doesn't fit into the quotient target register then a divide error exception is thrown. If you divide by `dx` either `dx` is zero or the result would be `>= 1_0000h` which doesn't fit into `ax`. Your formula `DX:AX = AX : r/m16` is incorrect. It is correct for `mul`. `div` is `ax = dx:ax / r/m16` and `dx = dx:ax % r/m16`

Comment: thanks the site I was referring to said this: dx: ax = ax: r / m16, from what I see however it is not correct, I had to understand it when it defined a word as 32bit

Comment: What site were you referring to?

Comment: In x86 terminology, a word is always 16-bit.  Consult Intel's manuals for correct pseudo-code: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div